# Why does my if condition not return the result? Is my if condition wrong?

Tags: asp.net-core, if-statement, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to implement an `if` condition to not generate ID or call the `_sysautoController.GUID` if my `Model.Reference` has an ID that already exists in the database.

I want it to not generate `ID` or call `_sysautoController.GUID` if `Model.Reference` is not null, and if `Model.Reference` is null or empty, that's the time it will call `_sysautoController.GUID` to generate an `ID`.

Here is my code that I have tried

```
if (Model.Reference != null)
{
            
}
else if (Model.Reference == null)
{
    _sysautoController.GUID(1, Model.TranCompNo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try it just like this

```
if (Model.Reference != null)
{
            
}
else
{
    _sysautoController.GUID(1, Model.TranCompNo);
}
```